# Using expression register without <C-r> in vim script

Tags: vim, neovim

I have a vim script that I am currently running with `nvim -s commands.txt file.txt`. I am trying to do something in the expression register with this script and I do not know how I can access it without the control key. I tried stuff like this:

```
:insert <C-r>=<C-r>"<Enter>
```

and even stuff like this:

```
^R=^R"
```

but to no avail.
All help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`-s` option requires data entered "as one types". That is, `:h recording` by "macro". Otherwise, you have to translate all the stuff into binary keycodes yourself. In particular, "control-r" becomes byte #18 etc.etc.

So it is always preferred to create ordinary VimScript file and use `:h :normal` when one needs to simulate key presses. Or, at least, prepare the file by "recording" feature. Trying to "compile into binary" by hand is no good.

Comment: Doesn't really answer my question :C. Is there a way to access the expression register when running a script with `-s`?

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely access the expression register in the context of a script, but not that way and, as Matt is hinting at, you probably don't need to.

First, `:help :insert` is supposed to be used like this:

```
:insert
Hello, world!
.
```

with:

- `:insert` on its own line,
- followed by the lines of text you want to insert,
- followed by a line with a single `.` to end the insertion.

which means that it will throw an error if you add anything after `:insert`.

Second, special characters, mappings, etc. are processed when using `:insert` *interactively*, in the command-line, but `-s` is not interactive, so you can forget about those `<C-r>`s.

In other words, I might be wrong but `:insert` is probably not what you want to begin with.

If you want to insert the content of the expression register *above* the current line, you can use `:help :put`:

```
:put!=1+2
```

If you want to insert the content of the expression register *below* the current line, you can use `:help :put` without the bang:

```
:put=1+2
```

If you want to insert the content of the expression register *before* the current character, you can use `:help P`:

```
"=1+2
P
```

If you want to insert the content of the expression register *after* the current character, you can use `:help p`:

```
"=1+2
p
```

If you want to use the content of another register as expression for the expression register, use `:help getreg()`:

```
:put=getreg('a')
```